# Hide dropdown values when no text

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I want dropdown values to be hidden if no text in search. Code below works like a charm for single selection. When multiple values selection is allowed it automatically shows all the dropdown values after user makes first selection.

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>

<select multiple class="form-control select-key" id="sel2" name="key-list[]">
  <option>SBI Cap</option>
  <option>PGIM MidCap</option>
  <option>Axis SmallCap</option>
  <option>Kotak Technology</option>
  <option>SBI Technology</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
   $("#sel2").selectize({
   onDropdownOpen: function($dropdown) {if (!this.lastQuery.length) {this.close(); this.settings.openOnFocus = false;}},   
  onType : function (str) {if (str === "") {this.close();}}
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dropdown stays open after you add an item. Just close it after the user adds an entry.

```js
$(function () {
   $("#sel2").selectize({
    onDropdownOpen: function($dropdown) {
        if (!this.lastQuery.length) {
        this.close(); 
        this.settings.openOnFocus = false;
      }
   },   
   onItemAdd: function() {
    this.close();
   },
   onType : function (str) {
        if (str === "") {
            this.close();
        }
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>

<select multiple class="form-control select-key" id="sel2" name="key-list[]">
  <option>SBI Cap</option>
  <option>PGIM MidCap</option>
  <option>Axis SmallCap</option>
  <option>Kotak Technology</option>
  <option>SBI Technology</option>
</select>
```